# redirect url with complex query string

Tags: .htaccess

I've tried using RewriteCond and RewriteRule to redirect a complex URL to a new page but without success.

The original URL:

index.php?option=com_k2&view=item&id=127&Itemid=353
or http://www.example.com/index.php?option=com_k2&view=item&id=127&Itemid=353

Have tried:

```
 RewriteRule ^index.php?option=com_k2&view=item&id=127&  Itemid=353$ http://www.example.com/somepage [R=301,L]
```

Also:

```
 RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} index.php?option=com_k2&view=item&id=127&Itemid=353
 RewriteRule http://www.example.com/somepage [R=301]
```

And:

```
 RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^id=127&Itemid=353$
 RewriteRule ^$ http://www.example.com/somepage [R=301]
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)id=127&Itemid=353(&|$)
RewriteRule ^(?:index\.php|)$ http://www.example.com/somepage [L,R=301]
```